# multi-level models and hierarchical models

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, multilevel-analysis, terminology

I am wondering what are the differences between multi-level modeling and hierarchical models? Are the in fact the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems me that are the same thing. From Wiki:

*Bayesian hierarchical modelling is a statistical model written in multiple levels*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modeling#Hierarchical_models

Moreover from some slide I read the two name as synonyms.